# Plugin para contagem de referências no VS 2013 Community

Tags: visual-studio-2013, plugin, extensão

Existe algum plugin para fazer a contagem de referências no ***Visual Studio 2013 Community*** como o do ***CodeLens***?

Não sabia que nessa versão ***CodeLens*** não faz parte dessa versão.

[image: no-codelens]